# Is their anyway to add a join to a query that returns the latest rows of a specific column using group by

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

```
 "SELECT * FROM report
      where id
        IN (
             SELECT MAX(id)
              FROM report
               where org_id = '$id'
                GROUP BY request_i
             ) ";
```

The code above gives me the latest row of each request_id per organization, which is exactly what i want but i need to use the FK in the table to get more details.
I want to join an organization & request table to the above query, so that i can use the FK to display certain things on my report page.

I tried the code below in different ways but i always get this error.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mou1\organizationDetails.php on line 503

```
"SELECT * FROM report
      JOIN request ON
      report.id = report.request_id
      JOIN organization ON
      organization.id = report.org_id
      where id
        IN (
             SELECT MAX(id)
              FROM report
               where org_id = '$id'
                GROUP BY request_i
             ) ";
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAP17.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What's going on with the question? There's been both a comment and answer given but no response. Unless you logged out of course, which is entirely possible. You mention an error; we need to know what that (exact) error is. Otherwise, we can't help you and cannot guess what that error is, unless we test this for you and debug it, for you. Now that isn't the way things work here on Stack Overflow. You need to work with us in order for us to help you. You see? It's a two-way street. One ways usually ends up with nothing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i posted the question right before going to bed, thanks for the suggestions tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, your query fails because `id` is ambiguous in the `WHERE` clause. You would need to qualify this column name:

```
SELECT * 
FROM report
JOIN request ON request.id = report.request_id
JOIN organization ON organization.id = report.org_id
WHERE report.id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM report
    where org_id = '$id'
    GROUP BY request_id
)
```

I fixed what seems like a typo in the join condition on `request` (you had `ON report.id = report.request_id`).

I would take one step forward and suggest to rewrite this query and use a correlated subquery. MySQL tend to poorly optimize `IN` flters with subqueries, while correlated subqueries generally perform very well if the proper index is available:

```
select *   -- you should enumerate the columns here
from report rep
inner join request req      on req.id = rep.request_id
inner join organization org on org.id = rep.org_id
where rep.id = (
    select max(rep1.id)
    from report rep1
    where rep1.org_id = ? and rep1.request_id = rep.request_id
)
```

Note that I used table aliases to make the query more readable and shorten it. You should also use a parameterized query rather than concatenating variables in the query string (the `?` stands for the query parameter here).

For performance with this query, you want an index on `report(org_id, requsst_id, id)`.

Comment: Nothing good ever came from `SELECT *` (I know; it's alluded to later, but still)

Comment: @Strawberry: thanks for commenting on the downvote. But to me, this is ridiculous. (1) The `select *` is mentioned in this answer - as you found out (2) It clearly does not relate to the error OP is facing  (3) We can’t suggest otherwise since we don’t see the table structures in the question (4) There is much more than that in the answer, as you can see (typo spotted, warning on SQL injection, suggestion of rephrasing the query, performance hint...)

Comment: I completely agree with all of that